# One to One Correspondence versus One to One Function

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm doing some discrete math reading and I am confused by the question "if A and B are infinite sets, is it possible for there to be a 1-1 function from A to B and a 1-1 function from B to A without there being a 1-1 correspondence from A to B?"

If I am correct in my thinking, the answer should be yes

Comment: 1-1 function generally means **injective** whereas 1-1 *correspondence* means **bijective**

Comment: Also, try to construct such a function that satisfies your criteria--I *highly* doubt you will be able to do so.

Answer (score 0):

False.

> **Schröder–Bernstein theorem:**
>   If there exist injective functions $f: A \to B$ and $g: B \to A$, then there exists a bijective function $h: A \to B$.

Mathematicians actually struggled with the proof of this theorem for a long time. The proof, as you would expect, involves constructing $h$ explicitly from $f$ and $g$. Intuitively, you should think of an injection $f$ from  $A$ to $B$ as saying there are "less elements" in $A$ than $B$ (because this implies a bijection with $f(A) \subset B$). In the case of this theorem, both sets have "less elements" than the other, so they must have the "same number" of elements.

N.B. This theorem proves the antisymmetry of the following relation:

> If $A$ and $B$ are sets, and $| \cdot |$ is the cardinal number, then $|A| \preccurlyeq |B|$ if and only if there is an injective function $f: A \to B$.

In particular, $\aleph_0$, $2^{\aleph_0}$, $\ldots$, make sense.

Comment: Do you have a historical reference for the fact that mathematicians struggle with the proof for some time? I believe I came across this theorem earlier today, but I never heard about it posing difficulty "back in the day."

Comment: "Georg Cantor conjectured in 1895 that $\preccurlyeq$ is antisymmetric. His student Felix Bernstein presented a proof in Cantor's seminar in 1897, and the proof appeared, properly attributed, in a 1898 book by Emile Borel. Also in 1898, Ernst Schroder gave an independent proof which, as he later acknowledged, was flawed." -- A Discrete Transition to Advanced Mathematics, Richmond & Richmond.   Considering Cantor laid the foundations for set theory and it took 2 years to prove a relatively basic fact, I would consider this a 'long time.' Then again, that's subjective.

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks for the info.